# Automatic refreshing of Styles and legends in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, legend, rule-based, refresh

I am a new QGIS user. I come from an Arcgis background, but in my current work for a public administration I must use QGIS for interoperability.

As an ArcMap user, I am used to certain "comforts", such as the automatic legend refresh, but also to the ability to personalize which elements to show and which not.

Here in QGIS I wasn't able to find a way to have the legend updated without adding again all the layers that where previously purged.

I need it because I'm trying to have a specific value to be showed in my Map/print layout, and I need that number (which is an area) to change every time I want to represent a new zone. What I need is a sort of automated layout in which quantities change accordingly to the area I select. Since I knew i could do this with ArcMap, I was sure to do the same in QGIS.

Is there a way to obtain this?

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions. I am not sure. To automatically make the legend update based on which layers are visible on the map. Select the legend and go to the item properties tab, and press the funnel icon (Filter Legend by Map Content). The second question, I am not sure what you are asking. Is it a data driven page like thing? It is called atlas in QGIS, a good tutorial is here: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html

Comment: Ps. If I misinterpreted  the question. Could you detail how you went about it using Arc?